# Stub all the method call including a method call inside it, from another class using mockito

Tags: mockito, powermockito

How to stub a System.currentTimeMillis() in the classB from classA?

Class A:

```
public classA {

  @Test   public void timeTest() {
      PowerMockito.mockStatic(System.class);
      PowerMockito.when(System.currentTimeMillis()).thenReturn(10L);
      B.testPowerMock();   }

}
```

Class B:

```
public class B {
    public static void testPowerMock() {
        System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis());
    }
}
```

Comment: Java has Clock class specifically made to simplify testing - it allows alternate clocks to be plugged in as and when required. Consider using it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. But our code using System.currentMilliseconds(). We can’t change it now and also the the method call invocation is inside of another method.